# Can't Install the MS Graph Powershell Extension

Tags: azure, powershell, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to do some Azure scripting with PowerShell.  To do that I need to install the `Microsoft.Graph` module.

To do that I run the following command:

`Install-Module Microsoft.Graph -Scope CurrentUser`

After selecting "Y" to continue, it hangs for about 5 seconds.  Then it seems to be doing the install.  (I see a couple of progress bars.)  Then they are replaced with an error that says I need admin rights.  Here is a screenshot:

[image: Admin Needed Error when Installing]

But I am an Admin, and I am running powershell in Admin mode.

I ran the following command that (supposedly) shows if you are an admin or not, and it returned `true`:

[image: I am an admin]

**How can I figure out what is causing this error?**

Comment: Curious. As an aside: If you want to avoid the interactive prompt in the future and you categorically trust modules available from the [PowerShell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/) (a pretty safe bet, I'd say), run `Set-PSRepository -InstallationPolicy Trusted PSGallery` as a one-time configuration step.

Comment: Another aside: The window title starting with `Administrator:` is itself a pretty good indicator that the session is elevated; a simpler command to verify elevation is to run `net session`, which only succeeds in elevated sessions.

Comment: @mklement0 - yeah this is weird.  I tried it on another machine and it worked just fine.  I can only guess that there is some kind of anti-virus or certificate issue with the machine having the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Need to check below:***

1. Check that the `PowerShellGet` and `PackageManagement` modules are up to date.
2. If you are using a proxy, the module installation may be restricted. Check that your proxy settings in PowerShell are accurate.
3. Try to use [-Force](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/powershellget/install-module?view=powershellget-2.x#syntax) parameter with the `Install-Module` command to avoid conflicts. It will work in some cases.
4. Certain `antivirus or firewall` software may interfere with PowerShell module installation in some instances. Disabling them for the duration of the installation could help in determining the issue.
5. You may also use the `Get-ExecutionPolicy -List` command to see if there are any extra sources that are blocking the installation of PowerShell modules even if you are running in administrator mode.

*After checked all the above, I tried to install* `Microsoft.Graph`  *extension in my environment and it worked as expected.*

```
Install-Module Microsoft.Graph -Scope CurrentUser
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer!  I tried the `-force` and it gave a different error: `Install-Package: Package 'Microsoft.Graph.DeviceManagement' failed to be installed because: Value cannot be null.`  I think that got me to a new layer of problems.  I will see if I can work past that.  (Thanks again!)